# Cannot access the internet in Metro

Tags: internet-connection, windows-8-preview, modern-ui

I am having one odd problem in Windows 8. Everytime I start my computer I need to connect manually to the internet with a username and a password. When I get connected I can access the internet in desktop mode, but not in Metro mode.

My internet connection icon in the bottom right of the screen is always showed with a warning sign (triangle and a "!" sign). If I right click the icon and go to Open Network And Sharing Center I can see my connection and the network card showing the message Unidentified Network.

Does someone know why I always get a warning sign, I'm sure thats why I can't access the internet in Metro.

Btw: I tried disable and enable of the network card.

Comment: Can you somehow figure out why it is Unidentified? Can you check the status and its details? Can you ping your router, your DNS server and an internet site?

Answer (score 1):

You should right click on the network tray icon and "Troubleshoot Problems". It's pretty much always given me a general idea of what went wrong.