# Windows 8 - "Metro" apps say "No internet connection."

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, modern-ui

I'm connected to Wifi on my laptop. I can access internet from the Desktop fine, but none of the metro (or whatever they're called now) apps can access the internet. For example, IE when opened on the Desktop, has no problem, but when opened from the tile, it won't connect.

The baffling thing is everything was working fine until a few days ago. Does anybody have any pointers as to what might be the problem? I've Googled around with no success.

Comment: Proxy settings?  Does it work for other user accounts?

Comment: Related: [Cannot access the internet in Metro](http://superuser.com/questions/396529/cannot-access-the-internet-in-metro), [Metro apps unable to connect](http://superuser.com/questions/504238/metro-apps-unable-to-connect)

Comment: @techie007, there's no proxy.

Comment: @Karan, I actually saw them before posting this. They have similar but not the same problem.

Comment: That's why I did not mark this as a duplicate. :)

Comment: Does it work for other user accounts?

Comment: @techie007, No it does not.