# Metro apps not connecting to the internet, but desktop apps can

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-connection, modern-ui

I've seen several questions around [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) and none seem to have an answer.
Besides the point, they seem to have a program or error in the way.

[Metro apps unable to connect](https://superuser.com/questions/504238/metro-apps-unable-to-connect)
[Cannot access the internet in Metro](https://superuser.com/questions/396529/cannot-access-the-internet-in-metro)

**My Question:** Is there any way I can get my metro apps to connect to the internet?

---

There seems to be something wrong with my metro apps, and none of them seem to be able to connect to the internet whatsoever, whereas all desktop apps work as per normal and have a perfectly fine internet connection.

Thinking there was a problem with the internet connection, I tried the troubleshooters, and to reset all wireless profiles and drivers. All of which did no change.
Note: *The Internet Connection troubleshooter came up with 'unknown problem'.*

I've tried booting the computer in safe mode (with networking) and as a [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/929135) and still, no change.

Before anybody goes on about anything:

- No, I do not use a VPN.
- No, my computer is *not* behind a proxy.
- I do not have an anti-virus program^.
- I've tried with the firewall disabled.
- I've tried running the metro apps as administrator. (Running Explorer as administrator)
- [My hosts file is empty.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/883821)

^ Apart from Windows Defender.

---

Before I get to the show-and-tell bit of this question (since all the pictures below take up *a lot* of space). My system specifications are:

- Laptop Model: DELL Latitude E6230
- RAM: 4GB (3.88GB usable)
- CPU: Quad-core Intel i5-3320M @ 2.60Ghz
- Operating System: Windows 8.1 Professional (Up to date with the latest updates)
- System Architecture: 64-bit OS and Processors

I'm pretty sure you guys are bored of seeing error messages after error message, but here's what happened:

Internet Explorer in Metro Mode:
[image: Internet Explorer in Metro Mode - Not working.]

Internet Explorer in Desktop Mode:
[image: Internet Explorer in Desktop Mode - Working.]

Windows Store (Metro App):
[image: Windows Store - Not working.]

Weather (Metro App)<sup>%</sup>:
[image: Weather App - Not working.]

<sup>%</sup> The live tile seems to be working correctly.

Steam (Desktop App):
[image: Steam Client - Definitely working.]

Comment: Just to confirm.  You have all updates installed?  In particular Update 1 ( Fall Update ) and Spring Update ( Update 2 ).

Comment: Yep. @Ramhound I'll update the question to reflect that too.

Comment: is the DNS service running? This is required for the new apps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was. I can't check now since I've upgraded to Win X